# Displaying an inverted half pyramid using a star pattern

Tags: c

I'd like to display an inverted half pyramid using a pattern made of "*" characters.
After running my code, the output seems empty. I'd like to know what is the problem.

Here's the desired output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

And here is my code:

```
for (int i=1;i<=5 ;i++)
{
    for(int x=5;x<=1;x--)
    {
        printf("* ");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: `i==1` should be `i=1`. Without seeing more of the code, there's no telling what else might be wrong.

Comment: `for(x=5;x<=1;x--)` How many times would you expect this loop to execute?

Comment: For the inner loop you probably meant `i >= 1`.

Comment: And please don't "fix" errors in your code, unless they happen to be typos made when posting the question itself. If you fix the code then you no longer have a problem, and the question becomes useless.

Comment: @Blaze this mistake i==1 here and i edit it but i wrote i=1  in IDE  (code blocks) and my output was empty so what is the problem?

Comment: @sarahamdy you say `x=5` and then execute the loop if `x<=1` . See the error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah exactly

Comment: @dragosht aha infinity so this should be larger then

Comment: Why *infinity*? The condition should be **true** for the loop to execute, so beeing x = 5 and beeing `5 <= 1` **false**, the inner loop is *never* executed.

Comment: @bob you are right this was the problem that there wasn't  output , so i fixed it and it works successfully but give me square as the first and inner loops count the same  times

Comment: Please note that both the answers you got already show and explain how to get a triangle instead of a square. Consider upvoting those, if they are helpful, and accept one. See e.g. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Bob__  okey ,i will do that

Comment: Thanks, well done. Now, the most important thing, have you understood *why* those "works" while your code doesn't?

Comment: sure i understood and learned thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generic solution to change the size of pyramid only once

```
for (int nb = 5; nb > 0; nb--) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        printf("* ");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: This code indeed works, but is not explained at all. I can understand it, but it would probably be better if you explained your solution instead of just providing it. 
Remember this old proverb: If you fish for a man, he'll have a meal, but if you teach him how to fish, he'll have meals for the rest of his life.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code.
The first one lies here:

```
for(int x=5;x<=1;x--)
```

You should check for x to be equal or larger to 1, not the opposite, since it is while this condition is true that the loop will be runnning.

But then, the output will be a square, not a rectangle. This is because neither the starting value nor the ending value of x changes. And finally, you might want to remove the space in your printf() if you wish having a result identical to the one you posted.

So here is the final, corrected code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5 ;i++)
{
    for(int x=5;x>=i;x--)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Running it will yield the correct output. Hope this helped.